# Inherit two classes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, easeljs, createjs

I'm creating a new class definition `Button` that extends an existing `Container` class in EaselJS. There are no problems with that. However, I'd also like `Button` to inherit from a super class `All`, so that `Button` also has access to its `.banana` and `.eatBanana`. How do I go about this?

```
(function() {

    function All() {
        this.banana = 0;
    }
    var p = All.prototype;

    p.eatBanana = function() {
        alert(this.banana);
    }

    window.All = All;
}());

(function() {

    function Button(apple) {
        this.apple = apple || 0;
        this.Container_constructor();
    }
    var p = createjs.extend(Button, createjs.Container);

    p.sayHi = function() {
       alert(this.apple + this.banana);
    }

    window.Button = createjs.promote(Button, 'Container');
}());
```

Comment: Not possible. Better make the All a property of the Button subclass or reverse.

Comment: If your class Container inherits from All, then you already have access to function from class All, but no programming language doesn't allow to inherit from more than 1 class, in most languages you have interfaces which you can implement as many as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript, and by extension CreateJS, does not support multiple inheritance. You could:

1. rethink your inheritance structure (ex. have Button extend All which extends Container)
2. mix-in members from All into your Button class or instances: `Button.prototype.doSomething = All.prototype.doSomething` or `myButton.doSomething = All.prototype.doSomething`.
3. inject members into a super class such as DisplayObject that is extended by all of the classes you want the members on: `DisplayObject.prototype.doSomething = All.prototype.doSomething`.

Comment: Thanks @gskinner for your answer. By the way, thank you very very much for the time and effort you put into CreateJS.